How to prevent hiding plotly chart bar on chart legend click
How to prevent hiding plotly chart bar on chart legend click in an angular application.
   <plotly-plot
        [divId]="graph.selectedGraph.name"
        [data]="graph.selectedGraph.data"
        [config]="graph.selectedGraph.config"
        [layout]="graph.selectedGraph.layout"
        (relayout)="draggedShape($event)"
        [ngClass]="{ 'single-data': graph.data && graph.data.length === 1 }"
        (legendClick)="launchColorPicker($event); $event.stopPropagation()"
      >
      </plotly-plot>


You need to disable the default Plotly behaviour by using event.preventDefault() or return false, so inside your launchColorPicker function.
  launchColorPicker(event: any) {
    // Your code ...

    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
    }
    return false;
  }


Its not working, Its hiding the chart bar
